# API to search inside video content

Tags: search-engine, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to know what API is avaiable to search inside video archive by specifying a text query (like [TalkMiner](http://talkminer.com) does).

Comment: no clarity. Please improve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for search specifically but you can quickly cook an application like Talkminer by joining two components - speech recognition engine and an indexer. For speech recognition you can use any avaialble engine like CMUSphinx, you first transcribe all the audio you need to search in.

For indexing you can use any indexing engine like Apache Solr. Just put the automatic transcriptions into the indexer and provide the query interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Koemei (https://koemei.com/). It's a service that you can use to index on demand videos and search inside them for specific moments of interest. Koemei also has search embed code for videos which you can embed on any website. And the service provides API you can use.